# {MS Access] How can I joint two tables without duplicate data?

Tags: excel, ms-access

I got two tables below:
[image: original tables]

And I want to create a query to combine them like below:
[image: desired result]

But unsuccessfully I got something like this:
[image: unsuccessful one]

Some data for "value1" duplicated
How can I solve this?
Is there any function that can have "value1" for the first "no." only?
Thank you.

Comment: I got two tables, and I want to create a query to combine them. But some data for "value1" duplicated How can I solve this? Is there any function that can have "value1" for the first "no." only? Thank you.

Comment: Build a report and use textbox HideDuplicates property.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using a subquery to prepare the data.

It seems you want only the rows with the lowest `Sub no` to join, so we'll first select that:

```
SELECT [No], Value2
FROM Table2 m
WHERE 
    EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 
        FROM Table2 s 
        WHERE s.[No] = m.[No]
        HAVING MIN(s.sub_no) = m.sub_no
    )
```

Then, integrate this into your main query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [No], Value2
    FROM Table2 m
    WHERE 
        EXISTS(
            SELECT 1 
            FROM Table2 s 
            WHERE s.[No] = m.[No]
            HAVING MIN(s.sub_no) = m.sub_no
        )
) AS T2 ON T1.[No] = T2.[No]
```